# Adding Models to Django Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with a foreign key, allowing me to reference an arbitrary amount of other models. So I can add and remove using the admin interface, but how can I do the equivalent programatically?

```
class Json(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()

class Dweet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    data = models.ForeignKey(Json)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use those models you can do the following:

```
>>> from app.models import Json, Dweet
>>> a = Json(data="asdf")
>>> a.save()
>>> b = Dweet(name="Test", data=a)
>>> b.save()
>>> c = Dweet(name="Test2", data=a)
>>> c.save()
```

After that you end up with one Json object and two Dweet objects that both point to said Json object. That's about as interesting as it gets with the two models you've shown us. You can add more Json objects if you like of course, but each Dweet can only point to one Json (not sure if you were asking for something different in your question).

Comment: Multiple `Json` objects in a `Dweet` as seen in the dropdown.

Comment: You're not actually putting multiple Json's in a single Dweet, it's giving you a choice of which Json to put in the Dweet. If you want multiple Json's in a given Dweet then you either need to put the ForeignKey in the Json instead of the Dweet (would make Json's non-reusable) or use a ManyToManyField (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: Thank you Crazy Costa for the clarification. I've asked this question three times, suffered numerous unnecessary downvotes, and finally I have reached an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what your problem is by the description provided but i would try to answer on the basis of what i can understand through the snapshot.

Actually one option is not listed twice in drop down rather it represents two model objects stored in Json table, i.e. as u have specified Json as foreign key. so each time you load the form it will request a queryset (like select * from Json). so in response it will receive model objects(Number of distinct rows in respective model table). So You need to specify a **unicode**() method in order to display object attribute value on the place of just ***Json Object***. So If you write a method like

```
class Json(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.data
```

You will get the data stored in Model object i.e. **data**.

Comment: That's not the problem. I don't care about the string representation.